# Why do we use primary key auto increment, and not just auto_increment?

Tags: sql, primary-key, auto-increment

Why do we use `PRIMARY_KEY_AUTO_INCREMENT` in SQL and not just `AUTO_INCREMENT` for an id in a table?

If we just set the data type of the id to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`, won't that automatically increment it, therefore generating a unique id each time? Thus, what is the point of setting `PRIMARY_KEY`(which uniquely identifies each item in the table) on top?

Comment: They do different things.  `auto_increment` defines how a default value is calculated for the column.  `primary key` specifies that the column uniquely identifies each row and is not `NULL`.  Some databases that support `auto_increment` insist that the column be used as a primary key.  It makes sense, but the declarations do different things.

Comment: Do you mean `primary key auto_increment`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of [constraints](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp), because SQL is a [declarative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming), and because it is self-documenting.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY` do two very different things.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is not standard SQL, but most databases have something like it. In usually makes the default an incrementing integer. That's the mechanistic element of a primary key: an auto-incrementing integer is a decent unique id.

`PRIMARY KEY` does a number of things.

1. The columns are `not null`.
2. The columns are `unique`.
3. (Non-standard, but almost always) The columns are indexed.
4. The columns are declared the primary key.
5. No other columns can be declared the primary key.

Most are *constraints* on the value. It must exist (1), it must be unique (2), and it must be the only primary key (5). Constraints guarantee the data is as you expect. Without them you might accidentally insert multiple rows with the same primary key, or with no primary key. Or the table might have multiple "primary" keys, which do you use? With constraints you don't have to check the data every time you fetch it, you know it will within its declared constraints.

Indexing the primary key (3) is an optimization. You're probably going to be searching by primary key a lot. Indexes aren't part of the SQL standard. That might be surprising. They're a detail of implementing SQL. Indexes don't affect the result of the query, and the SQL standard avoids telling databases *how* they should do things. This is part of why SQL is so ubiquitous, it is declarative.

In a declarative language you don't say how to do it, you say what you want. A SQL query says what result you want and the database figures it out for you. You could implement most of the above as constraints and triggers, but if you did the database wouldn't understand *why* you're doing that and would not be able to use that to help you out. By stating to the database "this is the primary key" and it can handle that as it sees fit. The database adds the necessary constraints. The database adds its optimizations, which can be more than indexing. The database can use this information in queries to identify unique rows. You get the benefit of 50 years of database theory.

Finally, it lets people know the purpose of the column. Anyone can read the schema and know that column is the primary key. That anyone can be you six months from now.

Answer (score 0):

By creating primary key, you create indexes. Indexes are useful to make queries quicker. You can create them manually but they are also created with primary and foreign keys.

Comment: This statement is ***NOT*** true for all databases - SQL Server for instance **DOES NOT** automatically create an index on a foreign key ....

Answer (score 0):

This is DBMS specific question. Let's try to find some common pros and cons.

Actually I don't think there is any similarities between defining a primary key or making any column auto incremental.

Primary keys need not to be incremental but unique.

If you just use a column as auto incremented then it's possible to have same value for multiple columns if you accidentally or purposefully reset the auto increment starting value.

But if you define it as primary key you need not to worry about that.
If it's a primary key then you can use it as foreign key in other tables.
In SQL Server primary key will create a cluster index automatically which will define the physical storage order of your data in tables.